# Wordpress in OpenShift/Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, redhat, podman

I'm just doing a wordpress deploy to practice openshift, I have this problem that I can't solve:

```
AH00558: apache2: Unable to reliably determine the FQDN of the server, using [10.128.2.60](https://10.128.2.60/). Globally set the "ServerName" directive to suppress this message
(13) Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: unable to connect to address \[::\]:80
(13) Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: unable to connect to address [0.0.0.0:80](https://0.0.0.0:80/)
no listening sockets available, switch off
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

This is my wordpress deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployments
metadata:
  name: wordpress
specs:
  replies: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      apps: wordpress
  templates:
    metadata:
      labels:
        apps: wordpress
    specs:
      containers:
      - name: wordpress
        image: wordpress:5.8.3-php7.4-apache
      ports:
      - containerPort: 8443
        name: wordpress
      volumeMounts:
      - name: wordpress-data
        mountPath: /var/www
      env:
      - name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
        value: mysql-service.default.svc.cluster.local
      - name: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: wp-db-secrets
            key: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      - name: WORDPRESS_DB_USER
        value: root
      - name: WORDPRESS_DB_NAME
        value: wordpress
      volumes:
      - name: wordpress-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: wordpress-volume
```

My Service:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: wordpress-service
specs:
  type: LoadBalancer
    selector:
      apps: wordpress
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8443
    targetPort: 8443
```

I should simply put the ip address it returns to me and log into wordpress

Comment: If you are learning, do not start with old versions, unless you need to. WordPress is at version 6.2 and PHP is at version 8.2. Use containers built with those versions or newer. 2) Configure your container to listen on port 8080 for http. You are using 8443 which by convention is for https. Where is SSL being handled? By your container or via a frontend load balancer? That will determine which ports you need to configure. Edit your post with more details so that a good answer is possible.  Include the Apache configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

Permission denied is on port 80, your configured port is 8443
Access it with :8443 or change it to Port 80

Comment: Sorry, I've only been doing this for a while, I don't quite understand what to do to solve it, because the pod doesn't start, it's in a crashloopback and it gives me that error

Comment: One idea would be to change `port: 8443` to `port: 80` in your service definition.

Comment: unfortunately the problem remains

Comment: Since it's not running as a privileged user Wordpress won't be able to listen on 80. You'll need to keep your YAML exposing 8443 and modify the Wordpress config to listen on 8443. I don't know anything about Wordpress so I don't know how to do that.

Comment: By convention port 8443 is expected to be https. Ports 80/8080 are expected to be http.